# Some posts shared to WhatsApp bring a thumbnail image, and others do not

Tags: whatsapp, meta-tags, share-open-graph

I am working on a website in which some posts shared to WhatsApp bring a thumbnail image, and others do not. They are the same post type, so the code is the same, og:images are all .jpg files that comply with the required dimensions and filesizes as far as I was able to find out about that. I have read to keep images under 2Mb.
Any suggestions?
This one brought a thumbnail image to the WhatsApp chat

This one did not

I read the documentation from Rank Math and found and checked details against what I read there, and have searched around the internet, and consulted Open AI. I have not found an answer.